# How to prevent PDO prepared statement adding the quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a `PDO` query like this.

```
$query=$this->con->prepare('SELECT ? FROM ? ');
$query->execute(array($rows,$table));
/*$rows="*"; $table="category";*/
```

Everything is OK in the coding. But when PDO executing my query it parse it as,

```
SELECT '*' FROM 'category'
```

So it's a wrong SQL statement.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''category'' at line 1
```

Please help me. How to prevent PDO from inserting the `'`s.

Comment: You cannot use PDO placeholders for things that affect the query structure. They are only valid where string/numeric literal are allowed.

Comment: Parameter binding only works on parameters, not database identifiers. You can only bind values, not table or column names

Comment: did you use the code like `select '*' from 'category'` means try to remove the `''`(single quotes) in the just like `select * from category`

Comment: Check `print_r(array($rows, $table))` and/or `print_r($table)`. I think the `category` is quoted there already. If so than leave PDO alone and get rid of the quotes there.